# I am trying to fix up an answer, but I am told that "posts can't contain that content."

Tags: support, edits, review

I was just perusing the 'review' page for first answers, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347183/force-non-www-and-https-via-htaccess/7479603#7479603), which I thought I could fix up.  Here is what I wanted to change it to:

```
You can't redirect to fix this because the SSL check happens before the HTTP connection 
has been fully made.

So, you have 3 options:

1. The best option is to get a cert that supports www and non-www. [RapidSSL](https://www.thesslstore.com/rapidssl/rapidssl-certificates.aspx) does this nicely, and most likely there are other vendors offering this as well.

1.  You can also get a wildcard cert that will let you do ANYTHING.mydomain.com. This can be more expensive, but most SSL Certificate vendors offer this, including [GoDaddy](http://help.godaddy.com/article/567).

1. The last choice is to purchase two separate certs, one for www and one for non-www.
```

The three main things I was trying to do with this edit were:

- fix formatting
- un-shorten links so people know where they are going (we don't need to conserve characters here), and inline the links
- make the answer less like an advertisment for a specific SSL certificate vendor.

I don't *think* that any of these things are/should be against the ToS.

So, how can I accomplish these goals (of making the answer more helpful to the community)?

Comment: Interestingly enough, this post (which contained the content from the prohibited post) was not blocked, perhaps because the content was in a code block.

Comment: Perhaps someone was spamming for GoDaddy or TheSSLStore and now links to those sites are no longer allowed?

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, I was unable to submit my edit.

Comment: @MatthewRead Good point.  Perhaps that is why the links were shortened in the first place... I wonder what kind of link would be appropriate here, to not necessarily favor one vendor over another. I looked for wikipedia articles, but none seemed to really be appropriate for this. I would be afraid that a google search results page listing many vendors offering these services would be seen as a LMGTFY type of thing (which seems to be frowned upon).

Comment: `www.thesslstore.com` is blocked on StackOverflow (but not on meta) for whatever reason; that's why you couldn't submit your edit.

Comment: PS: Please don't inline your links. Use the `[link text][1]` and `[1]: http://example.org` syntax instead.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ, both link formats are absolutely supported.  Is there a reason you are telling users not to use a supported format?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff It renders the question hard to read, especially with longer links (when in edit mode). I remember seeing a post somewhere by Jeff or Sam (Saffron) recommending the usage of the "reference" syntax. I personally prefer it for clarity. I only use the other format on comments.

Comment: Another thing is the inline syntax breaks if the link has a right parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focusing on your edit, you mention that you want to make the answer less like an advertisement for a specific vendor.  However, it looks like you solved that by adding a link to another vendor.  I disagree that this makes the answer less an advertisement.  Now you're just advertising 2 companies instead of 1.  What if these links go bad?  Teach the user what they need to know without advertising.

Comment: That is a good point, and one I was having trouble with myself (see my comment to [Matthew Read above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106891/i-am-trying-to-fix-up-an-answer-but-i-am-told-that-posts-cant-contain-that-con/106893#comment-274579)).

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes links to a commercial product are necessary. That doesn't mean they are advertisements.

Comment: @pkaeding Why do you need to link to a vendor or a google search?  Can't people do that themselves?  Provide content, make it something useful for people to read and learn.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ, you're right, but in this case I don't think it's absolutely necessary to include the link.

Comment: Why link to documentation? Can't people find that themselves? Providing links makes it easier for people to find additional content that your answer can't feasibly cover. It's a matter of convenience.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ, in this case, as you stated in your since-deleted answer, that's not going to work, so yeah, that answer is just fine without the link.